# how to choose between two IRC cloaks

Tags: irc

- unaffiliated/xxxxx :is now your hidden host (set by services.)
- gateway/shell/xxxxx :is now your hidden host (set by syn.)

Is it possible to choose between one of these irc cloaks?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is about the freenode network, as these cloaks look like theirs.

“unaffiliated/xxxxx” is only given for users who request it. So if you don't want it, you could ask the network operators to remove it.

“gateway/shell/xxxxx” is (I believe) given to users of a particular shell until they log in. So if you don't want it, just connect to your account, if it has the “unaffiliated/xxxxx” cloak (and if it does not, request it to the network operators).